# remove formatting but only for specific columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script, which amongst other things removes any formatting from my sheets.  Works perfect, but I need to make a small change.

Instead of removing formatting from the entire sheet, I would just like to remove formatting from columns B - Y (all rows).

My code is below, does anyone know how I could tweak it?

Thanks guys

```
   function pricesearchsheet2() {

    var date = new Date();
    var currenthour = date.getHours();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var cellcolour = "RED";
    var celltoleft = 0;
    var pastprice = 0;
    var currentprice = 0;
    var sending = "n";
    var tradingemailsfield = "C4";
    var playername = "null";
    var playernamecell = "A3";

  var targetcell = 1

// set the target cell based on the current hour of the day
  if (currenthour == 0) {
  var targetcell = "B6";
  var celltoleft = "A6";
}
if (currenthour == 1) {
  var targetcell = "C6";
  var celltoleft = "B6";
}
if (currenthour == 2) {
  var targetcell = "D6";
  var celltoleft = "C6";
}
if (currenthour == 3) {
  var targetcell = "E6";
  var celltoleft = "D6";
}
if (currenthour == 4) {
  var targetcell = "F6";
  var celltoleft = "E6";
}
if (currenthour == 5) {
  var targetcell = "G6";
  var celltoleft = "F6";
}
if (currenthour == 6) {
  var targetcell = "H6";
  var celltoleft = "G6";
}
if (currenthour == 7) {
  var targetcell = "I6";
  var celltoleft = "H6";
}
if (currenthour == 8) {
  var targetcell = "J6";
  var celltoleft = "I6";
}
if (currenthour == 9) {
  var targetcell = "K6";
  var celltoleft = "J6";
}
if (currenthour == 10) {
  var targetcell = "L6";
  var celltoleft = "K6";
}
if (currenthour == 11) {
  var targetcell = "M6";
  var celltoleft = "L6";
}
if (currenthour == 12) {
  var targetcell = "N6";
  var celltoleft = "M6";
}
if (currenthour == 13) {
  var targetcell = "O6";
  var celltoleft = "N6";
}
if (currenthour == 14) {
  var targetcell = "P6";
  var celltoleft = "O6";
}
if (currenthour == 15) {
  var targetcell = "Q6";
  var celltoleft = "P6";
}
if (currenthour == 16) {
  var targetcell = "R6";
  var celltoleft = "Q6";
}
if (currenthour == 17) {
  var targetcell = "S6";
  var celltoleft = "R6";
}
if (currenthour == 18) {
  var targetcell = "T6";
  var celltoleft = "S6";
}
if (currenthour == 19) {
  var targetcell = "U6";
  var celltoleft = "T6";
}
if (currenthour == 20) {
  var targetcell = "V6";
  var celltoleft = "U6";
}
if (currenthour == 21) {
  var targetcell = "W6";
  var celltoleft = "V6";
}
if (currenthour == 22) {
  var targetcell = "X6";
  var celltoleft = "W6";
}
if (currenthour == 23) {
  var targetcell = "Y6";
  var celltoleft = "X6";
}
if (currenthour == 24) {
  var targetcell = "Z6";
  var celltoleft = "Y6";
}
    for (var sheet of sheets) {
      sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=--SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(",",IMPORTDATA(B1)),"LCPrice"":""(.*)"), CHAR(34))');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      var range = sheet.getDataRange();


     
      range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
            
      //GET THE VALUE FROM THE CURRENT CELL AND THE PREVIOUS CELL, COMPARE THE VALUES IN ORDER TO WORK OUT IF PRICE HAS GONE UP OR DOWN.
      var pastprice = sheet.getRange(celltoleft).getValue();
      var currentprice = sheet.getRange(targetcell).getValue();

      if (currentprice == pastprice) {
        cellcolour = "orange"
      }
      else if (currentprice > pastprice) {
        cellcolour = "green"
      }
      else {
        cellcolour = "red"
      }
      sheet.getRange(targetcell).setBackground(cellcolour);
      //end of set colour functionality

// Send an email if the email request cell is set to Y
var tradingemailsfield = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
var playersname = sheet.getRange('A3').getValue();
if (tradingemailsfield == "y") {
MailApp.sendEmail("my@mail.co.uk", "Price Alert For "+playersname, "The price of "+playersname+" has moved from "+pastprice+" to "+currentprice+" ");   
}
else{

}

    }


}
```

Comment: sorry. edited to include all code.

Comment: And sorry, it makes no sense to answer to someone who doesn't accept correct answers. https://imgur.com/ZBbCezG.png

Comment: What formatting are you talking about.  I'll answer your question if I can if you return and accept the correct answers that Yuri has identified, other wise forget it.  BTW you can greatly reduce your code size.  I have it down to 23 lines

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Voting (when you have sufficient privileges) and accepting answers to your questions are both completely optional actions - but they are recommended.

Comment: Very frustrating that I literally dont have the option to mark correct answers.

Comment: I can see that you have, in fact, accepted some answers now, so it looks like you figured it out.

Comment: Again I ask what formatting are you talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

> Instead of removing formatting from the entire sheet, I would just like to remove formatting from columns B - Y (all rows).

#### clearFormat:

You can remove format from a range easily with [Range.clearFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearFormat()).

Here's an example of clearing format for columns `B-Y` in all sheets:

```
function clearFormat() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    sheet.getRange("B:Y").clearFormat();
  });
}
```

#### copyTo:

Since `clearFormat` might not reset some formatting rules and it's not clear what formatting do you want to clear, you could also use [Range.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options), as you are already doing, but with range `B:Y` instead of all sheet:

```
function copyTo() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const range = sheet.getRange("B:Y");
    range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
  });
}
```